# Abelian Hitchin's equations

Tags: abelian-groups, moduli-space

I'm a physicist by trade, and I've recently been working with the dimensional reduction of 4d supersymmetric gauge theories. In particular, the GL-twisted $\mathcal{N}=4$ gauge theory with a simple gauge group $G$ reduces on two compact dimensions to a 2d sigma model with its target being the moduli space of Hitchin's equations (See [Kapustin-Witten](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0604151) for more information). Being simple, it means that we can't have any abelian gauge groups. This got me thinking about what it means if we get $G=U(1)$.

So my question is this: Is there an abelian version of Hitchin's equations?

Comment: Yes, of course: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402429

Comment: Thank you for the response! I knew mathematicians are nice. Anyway, the Hitchin's equations may be written as 
$F-\phi\wedge\phi\phi=0$ and $D\phi=0=D^*\phi=0$, where $F$ and $\phi$ are,respectively, a curvature 2-form and a 1-form, both valued in the gauge group $G$, and $D$ is a covariant derivative. To be clear now -- what you're saying is that the abelian version is simply the set of equations written above, but with $G=U(1)$? So these equations simplify to $F=0$ and $D\phi=0=D^*\phi=0$ -- we get flat connections.

Comment: @MoisheKohan is there a version of Hitchin's equations for non-compact groups like $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$? A reference would be enough if there is such a reference. Whatever I read/find was about compact groups.

Comment: @QGravity: Did you read Hitchin's original 1987 paper?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yeah but he only discusses groups over complex numbers not real numbers, as far as I remember. Moduli of $G$-Higgs bundles are defined for arbitrary **complex** Lie group like $\text{SL}(N,\mathbb{C})$, and possibly can be defined for _compact_ real Lie groups but my main confusion is **real** noncompact Lie groups lie $\text{SL}(N,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @QGravity: He discusses $SL(2,R)$ as well. He discusses real noncompact forms even more in his follow up paper in "Topology" (1992, I think).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, thank you. You probably mean this one, right? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004093839290044I

Comment: @QGravity: Right.